# Вопрос с mysql, ajax, php

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Я пишу чат с помощю php, mysql, ajax и jQuery. Имя моей таблицы в mysql-е messages, в нем есть 3 столбика id, message и date. С помощю функции submit() я показываю на экране мои сообщения. Как можно сделать так чтобы с помощю функции timedMsg() вывесвти из сервера сообщениия добаленние другими после моего последного сообщения?

Answer (score 1):

Ну во первых отправка сообщения не означает что вам необходимо убирать интервал проверок на сервере(это на всякий случай), соотсветственно у вас должно быть 2 XMLHttpRequest обьекта, один будет заниматся проверкой сообщений а другой отправкой(это может решить проблему "конфликта" запросов, т.е. чтобы сообщения чекались и тогда когда сообщение отправляется)

Ну а вообще как вариант просто держвать в сессии например `$_SESSION['lastMessageId']` и по нему смотреть уже на сервере...
Можно и в куках хранить, можно в display:none html элементе, это уже не столь важно...
Ну и естественно + на сервере надо смотреть это значение... Реализовав все это вы предусмотреть случай медленного интернет соединения ну и + возможную конфликтность запросов...(если у вас уже это не реализовано естественно)

Answer (score 0):

Отправляйте запрос серверу, а там смотрите есть ли сообщения, например, с id большим чем id вашего последнего сообщения. И если таковые имеются, то отдавай их клиенту. Всё просто.

Comment: ну а как определить больше или меньше id ?

Comment: Отправляете на серверную часть кроме всего прочего еще и id последнего сообщения, и выбираете с id больше этого id..

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, в таблице должно быть поле user ( кто отправил это сообщение ).
Тогда запрос будет таким:

```
$sql = 'select * from `messages` where `id` > ( select `id` from `messages` where `user` = '.$uid.' order by `date` desc limit 0,1 )';
```

Обратите внимание на $uid, там нужно поставить id человека